# Mysql Match against query with special charters search

Tags: php, mysql

I have following match against query which searches records from database table based on search phrase.

```
    SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE MATCH (catchall) AGAINST ('"horse"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This query works properly. When search phrase contains special characters like '(' etc It just skips such special characters.
If i search for "(horse)" it gives me same result as it gives for "horse".

```
    SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE MATCH (catchall) AGAINST ('"(horse)"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Does it mean match against query doesn't work with special characters or am i missing something. Please suggest. Thanks.
I tried by removing IN BOOLEAN MODE from the query but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> Parentheses group words into subexpressions. Parenthesized groups can be nested.

if you want to treat prenthes as "word chars", there are two possibilitys:

> If you want to change the set of characters that are considered word
>   characters, you can do so in two ways. Suppose that you want to treat
>   the hyphen character ('-') as a word character. Use either of these
>   methods:
>
> Modify the MySQL source: In myisam/ftdefs.h, see the true_word_char()
>   and misc_word_char() macros. Add '-' to one of those macros and
>   recompile MySQL.
>
> Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The
>   true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish
>   letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the
>    contents in one of the character set XML files to specify
>   that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for your
>   FULLTEXT indexes.
>
> After making the modification, you must rebuild the indexes for each
>   table that contains any FULLTEXT indexes.

a third way would be to not use `MATCH ... AGAINST` at all and use `LIKE` instead - but this might get complicated (if you want to use the other operators of ful-text-searches such as `+`/`-`) and slow down your query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @oezi. Should i add all the special characters so that it works with matach against query like ; ' "" , etc. Does this create any security whole or is it completely safe. I don't wanna go with like query.

Comment: this doesn't create security holes or something like that - but you won't be able to use the features of those special chars anymore, so i'd only add the ones absolutely neccessary.

Comment: Got it. @oezi one last question is there any way to escape the characters in the query?